# TicTacToe game not taking users input

Tags: java, oop, tic-tac-toe

Im making a tictactoe game, everything works fine so far but its not taking my coordinates, I need the icon that is given to me to be put where im writing it to go on the board. Here's my code:

Main class:

```
package com.mycompany.tictactoe;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tictactoe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Player player1 = new Player();
        Player player2 = new Player();

        player1.icon = 'X';
        player1.PlayerInfo();

        player2.icon = 'O';
        player2.PlayerInfo();

        Board board = new Board();

        boolean GameOver = false;

        while (!GameOver) {
            board.PrintBoard(board.board);
            Player currentPlayer = (board.Row + board.Col) % 2 == 0 ? player1 : player2;
            System.out.print("Player " + currentPlayer.name + " enter row value as " + currentPlayer.icon + ": ");
            int row = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Player " + currentPlayer.name + " enter col value as " + currentPlayer.icon + ": ");
            int col = scanner.nextInt();

            if (row >= 0 && row < 3 && col >= 0 && col < 3) {
                if (board.board[row][col] == ' ') {
                    board.board[row][col] = currentPlayer.icon;
                    GameOver = Board.HaveWon(board.board, currentPlayer);
                    if (GameOver) {
                        System.out.println("Player " + currentPlayer.name + " has won");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid move.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, row and column values must be between 0 and 2.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
package com.mycompany.tictactoe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char icon;
    String name;

    public void PlayerInfo() {
        System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Board class:

```
package com.mycompany.tictactoe;

public class Board {
    int Row = 0;
    int Col = 0;
    char[][] board = new char[3][3];

    public void PrintBoard(char[][] board) {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(board[row][col] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (row < board.length - 1) {
                System.out.println("---------");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean HaveWon(char[][] board, Player player) {
        //Check the rows
        for (int Row = 0; Row <  board.length; Row++){
            if(board[Row][0] == player.icon && board[Row][1] == player.icon && board[Row][2] == player.icon){
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        //Check for Colums
        for (int Col = 0; Col <  board[0].length; Col++){
            if(board[0][Col] == player.icon && board[1][Col] == player.icon && board[2][Col] == player.icon){
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        //Check diagonaly
            if(board[0][0] == player.icon && board[1][1] == player.icon && board[2][2] == player.icon){
                return true;
            }
            
            if(board[0][2] == player.icon && board[1][1] == player.icon && board[2][0] == player.icon){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
    }
```

If you have any other suggestions on how to make my code better i would be very grateful :)

Comment: Var names begin with lowercase letter, not uppercase. Ditto for method names.

Comment: As a beginner, generally best to avoid `static` until you are very clear on its purpose.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging

Comment: I don't see where you initialize the board squares to the space character ' ' - you need that for your "move" logic to succeed.  (see `if (board.board[row][col] == ' ') {`

Comment: It seems you never give feedback to answers, let be you have marked an answer as accepted. Not very motivating.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Im making a tictactoe game, everything works fine so far but its not taking my coordinates ..."*

The reason is because the *board* array needs to be initialized with space characters.
You check for it, within the *main* loop.

```java
if (board.board[row][col] == ' ')
```

I used the *[Arrays#fill](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(char%5B%5D,char))* method here, to avoid having to write another loop.
And I added it to the default constructor.  You could technically use the *[initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)*, as well.

```java
Board() {
    for (char[] row : board) Arrays.fill(row, ' ');
}
```

> *"... If you have any other suggestions on how to make my code better i would be very grateful :)"*

Since the *board* is just a *3* x *3*, I wouldn't use any loops.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return
          " %s | %s | %s %n".formatted(board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2])
        + "%s%n".formatted("-".repeat(11))
        + " %s | %s | %s %n".formatted(board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2])
        + "%s%n".formatted("-".repeat(11))
        + " %s | %s | %s".formatted(board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
}
```